# Are Gallifreyans reptiles, mammals, or something else?

Tags: biology, time-lord, gallifrey, doctor-who

**I recently saw a claim that Gallifreyans are reptiles.**

I know that their normal internal temperature is significantly lower that that of humans.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Lord#Physical_characteristics) (emphasis mine):

> Physiological differences from humans include two hearts which
>   normally beat at 170 beats per minute, **an internal body temperature of
>   15 degrees Celsius (59 degrees Fahrenheit)** and a "respiratory bypass
>   system" that allows them to survive strangulation. Time Lords can also
>   survive full exposure to the vacuum of space with no ill effects,
>   though when in a vacuum for an extended period, a Time Lord must take
>   a supply of air along or suffocate. Time Lords also seem to have an
>   increased resilience to higher frequencies of sound, as seen in "The
>   Christmas Invasion" and "Partners in Crime". If severely injured, Time
>   Lords can go into a healing coma which lowers their body temperature
>   to below freezing.

However, that alone does not indicate being reptiles. It doesn't even indicate their being ectothermic (cold blooded). They could be endotherms with a lower internal body temperature than humans.

**Is there any definitive evidence in the show (books, comics, etc) or in interviews or behind-the-scenes resources as to this?**

Comment: Gallifreyans are neither reptiles nor mammals: they're **aliens**. Reptiles and mammals are classes of animals found on the planet Earth, also known as Sol 3. Why should the inhabitants of the constellation of Kasterborous fall into the Linnean classification system?

Comment: i guess you could ask, are they most like x y or z.

Comment: "Gallifreyans could survive some falls which would shatter the bones of humans."..... If you need to link Gallifreyans with something from Earth, I vote for cats!!!

Comment: @Saphirel Would that make the show Doctor Mew?

Comment: The answer to the question is: yes.

Comment: Time Lords can adjust time, so some of those weird resistances could simply be Time Lord shenanigans rather than gallifrayan nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are Gallifreyans repriles or mammals or birds or fish?

**No.**

As @randal'thor says in his comment, they're aliens.  Reptiles/mammals are groups of life forms on earth, and aliens do not necessarily fit into any of these categories.  They may look like humans--I mean, humans look like Gallifreyans--but they are not related in any way to any type of life form on Earth.

[Unless](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/c7/c7efa27fd02af2ee883edee32a8dea4fc101c81aefe7eeeb3e8e5ae162b98f7f.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/35gaj6&h=481&w=550&tbnid=7vIq0H-i78dVRM:&docid=AhrQCH6HCRukjM&hl=en&ei=CJG7VsGwB8Kw-QHI4bmIBg&tbm=isch&client=safari&ved=0ahUKEwjB1IjO-O3KAhVCWD4KHchwDmEQMwgcKAAwAA)...